# why Image button hide behind the surface view after take picture?

Tags: android, android-camera

in Customised camera after take picture the retake image button hide behind the surface view which shows the taken picture.

Comment: can you show your code of layout? Or if you are using an relative/frame layout your button should be after the surfaceview not before the surfaceview in which you are displaying taken photo

Comment: thanks for reply.i got the solution i am using the button after the surface view only but even though it get hided.i put android:visibilty="Invisible" to that button instead of if i put android:visibilty="gone" means it is not hiding. now i got the soultion but whats the difference between using of gone instead of invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space in layout.

View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes space for layout purposes.

Comment: it is ok in while layout designing but after take picture button hides behind surface view if i use View.INVISIBLE in layout designing.please give solution.

Comment: <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/retake_button"
        android:visibility="gone" />

Comment: I was mean to whole layout..